# JQuery event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, bind

I'm loading from DB some html (using ajax post request), it looks like:

```
<div id="slides_control">
   <div>
      <a href="#"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

With html I also load JS-code:

```
<script>
$('#slides_control a').bind('click', function() {
   alert('achtung');
});
</script>
```

Script goes right after the html (in received data).

But when I click at some link inside new html, I don't see the alert. What's wrong?

---

I also tried to bind it after ajax ended:

```
$.post('page.php', {}, function(data) {
    document.write(data);
    $('#slides_control a').bind('click', function() {
       alert('achtung');
    });
});
```

Didn't help me.

Comment: Can you trace your code with your browser's developer tools to see what executes when you click on an `<a>` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably running bind function before your html has been loaded, so it does not find element

So, put your code to run on dom load:

```
$(function(){
    $('#slides_control a').bind('click', function() {
       alert('achtung');
   });
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the jQuery call:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#slides_control a').bind('click', function() {
      alert('achtung');
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

execute this script when data is loaded. You are executing this script before data is loaded.